# How to count the number of checked checkboxes on blur event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to count the number of checked checkboxes on blur event. But it looks like the number of blur events is being counted. How to count the number of checked checkboxes in array?

```js
const requiredBoxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.js-form-checkbox')];
requiredBoxes.forEach(function (input) {
    input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
        console.log(requiredBoxes.filter(item => item.checked).length);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="js-form-checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="js-form-checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="js-form-checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="js-form-checkbox" />
```

Comment: Can you please clarify? Your code seems to be working as intended

Comment: As a side-note, you can do `.document.querySelectorAll('.js-form-checkbox:checked').length` to get how many are checked as well without having to use the filter method.

Comment: I think the problem is that the `blur` event is the wrong event; you may want to use `change` instead ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pqw58d6k/)).

Comment: It counts not correct because of blur.

Answer (score 0):

The clicks are not being counted, when you press the checkbox, you don't see the blur event immediately. You can check by checking the checkbox and clicking elsewhere but checkboxes.